# Connecting to an EC2 instance from a nestJS web app is failing

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I have an app in nestJS I am trying to connect to an EC2 instance for mongoDB. I have successfully started a port forwarding session to the EC2 instance with aws start-session ......
and connected with my authentication details using mongoDB compass and also with my mongo shell so I am sure this connection is solid and working. However I have been configuring my nestJS app to make the connection too and it errors out every time:

This is the error:

13:03:49] Starting compilation in watch mode...

[13:03:57] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[Nest] 212100  - 13/08/2023, 13:04:03     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 212100  - 13/08/2023, 13:04:03     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +20ms
[Nest] 212100  - 13/08/2023, 13:04:03     LOG [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 212100  - 13/08/2023, 13:04:03     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 212100  - 13/08/2023, 13:04:03     LOG [InstanceLoader] MediaModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 212100  - 13/08/2023, 13:04:03     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 212100  - 13/08/2023, 13:04:33   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND [mongodb1.kelvin.rs](http://mongodb1.kelvin.rs/)
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\lawre\MM_Repositories\nestjs-demo-api\node_modules\mongodb\src\sdam\topology.ts:567:30)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
[Nest] 212100  - 13/08/2023, 13:05:06   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)...
MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND [mongodb1.kelvin.rs](http://mongodb1.kelvin.rs/)
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\lawre\MM_Repositories\nestjs-demo-api\node_modules\mongodb\src\sdam\topology.ts:567:30)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)

this is the database.ts:

```
<pre><code>
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmOptionsFactory, TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import {DatabaseType} from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class TypeOrmConfigService implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
  @Inject(ConfigService)
  private readonly config: ConfigService;

  public createTypeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    // TODO: we'll need to add type over Type funtion on string literals to by pass The Type Guard
    const returnObj =  {
      type: this.config.get<string>('DB_TYPE') as DatabaseType,
      host: this.config.get<string>('DB_HOST'),
      port: this.config.get<number>('DB_PORT'),
      username: this.config.get<string>('DB_USERNAME'),
      password: this.config.get<string>('DB_PASSWORD'),
      authSource: this.config.get<string>('DB_AUTHSOURCE'),
      database: this.config.get<string>('DB_NAME'),
      entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.{ts,js}'],
      synchronize: false,
    };

    return returnObj as TypeOrmModuleOptions
  }
}

</code></pre>
```

This is the app.module.ts:

```
<pre><code>
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config'
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ExamModule } from './exam/exam.module';
import { MediaModule } from './media/media.module';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { TypeOrmConfigService } from './common/database';
import { APP_GUARD } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth.guard';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ExamModule,
    MediaModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({useClass: TypeOrmConfigService}),
    JwtModule.register({
      global: true,
      secret: process.env.SECRET_TOKEN,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: AuthGuard,
    },
    AppService,
  ],
  
})

export class AppModule {}
</code></pre>
```

I have checked and re checked the authentication details in my .env and it's correct. I have tried checking no other local mongo servers are up and interfering with things. I have checked any potential firewall issues. I am not sure where the host name "mongodb1.kelvin.rs" in the error is coming from. Again I can connect to my EC2 instance through mongo compass and through mongo shell so there is something from the side of this nestJS app that is trying to resolve the incorrect hostname as far as I can see.

NB I can configure it to connect to a local mongo server when I run

mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0

and close the EC2 ssm instance.